# "Делай что должно, и пусть будет что будет." или "Делай, что должно, и пусть будет, что будет."

Tags: запятые, союзные-слова

Если вторая запятая (между двумя глаголами будет и будет) не вызывает, наверное, вопросов, то первая запятая (между глаголом и наречием (ведь **надо** - наречие, не так ли?)) - другое дело.

Встречаются примеры без запятой:

```
Делай что должно, и пусть будет что будет
Ну, делай что должно, и будь что будет 
Сказать старикам, они сделают что надо. 
Ваня сделает что надо.
... там Кара-Кончар сделает что надо.
Жди, сами сделают что надо.
```

Но встречаются и обратные примеры:

```
Так-то и вы делайте, что должно, и думайте (Толстой)
... чтобы мы делали, что должно, ― сказал Нехлюдов, (Толстой)
«Делай, что должен, и пусть будет, что будет».
Делай, что должно, и пусть будет что будет
Они делают, что должно.
```

Как правильно и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Диалог**

– Я – фразеологизм, и поэтому меня не трогайте. А если меня немного изменить, то все равное я еще фразеологизм, опять же не трогайте. – Да ладно тебе,  как раз менять-то ничего нельзя. –  Нет, можно! Если немного, то можно.

Цитата из ответа: "Чуть изменённый фразеологизм - всё равно фразеологизм. Так и "Грамота" считает..."

2. Никогда я не понимала таких рассуждений, вот и Толстой к подобным фразеологизмам относился без должного почтения.

А что же делать? Да у Розенталя на эту тему простейшее решение:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

1. Перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний запятая не ставится: *выполнить как должно* (как надо, как нужно).

Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот **не образует придаточной части** сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения. Так, в сочетании "*говорит об этом где только может*" выделенные слова имеют значение ‘везде’.

Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных словосочетаний употреблено **не в качестве фразеологизма**, то оно может образовать придаточную часть (обычно неполное предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: *Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно* — ‘везде’; *Поставить, где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания* — ‘где это нужно’.

3. **Интонационное решение**

Не знаете, что выбрать? Да всё очень просто. Интонация там разная. Запятая ставится при наличии двух ударений, когда вы хотите подчеркнуть глагол.

(1) Делай что должно, и пусть будет что бУдет.

(2) Делай, что должно, и пусть бУдет, что бУдет.

В школьной практике, конечно, **запятую лучше не ставить**, там рисковать не стоит. Но мы-то Толстого обсуждаем. В художественной литературе это авторское решение — от контекста зависит, от общего стиля. Там школьные форматы — это не главное.

А вот **замена оборота словами** — это формальный прием, здесь не семантика важна (можно слово подобрать или нельзя). При такой проверке мы определяем, насколько позиция фразеологизма соответствует позиции второстепенного члена (дополнения в данном случае), то есть **проверяем структуру** заданного предложения.

Comment: "насколько позиция фразеологизма соответствует позиции обстоятельства"  --Здесь позиция дополнения, а не обстоятельства. Сравните: Делай что должно = Делай должное. (дополнение!) Нахождение подходящей замены как раз и показывает явное тяготение "придаточного" к "дополнению". В остальном согласен. Интересно, как синтаксис словосочетаний вторгается в синтаксис предложения и конкурирует с ним. Сравните: На небе не было ни облачка. (Стандартный синтаксис предложения). Но: На небе было ни облачка (синтаксис словосочетания вторгся в синтаксис предложения)

Comment: Ну да, дополнение, извините за небрежность (а то я уже устала себя извинять за это).  Я поправлю ответ. Со всем согласна, креативно рассуждаете.

Answer (score 2):

Это чуть реконструированная фраза из пословицы: *Делай что должно, и будь что будет.* Два предложения - две поговорки (фразеологизмы), соединённые союзом И,
а во фразеологических оборотах запятые не ставят, там нет придаточных предложений, это обороты. Чуть изменённый фразеологизм - всё равно фразеологизм. Так и "Грамота" считает:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: Окей, фразеологизм и точка. Но что насчет похожих конструкций типа: "но он взлезал и делал что надо." (Толстой, Каренина), "Потому что они понимают как надо." и тп. ?
Возможно ли тут сослаться на правило замены:
 "но он взлезал и делал должное.", "Потому что они понимают должным образом."